# What happens when svnserve gets stopped (SIGKILLED) while a commit is in progress?

Tags: logrotate, svnserve

What happens when svnserve gets stopped (SIGKILLed) while a commit [to an FSFS repository] is in progress ?  (I mean has svnserve been made robust enough to handle this, say upon restart, or must the repositories all be considered corrupted ?)

Likewise, what happens inside svnserve [to the handle on the currently open log file] when logrotate or some such tries to do its magic on svnserve's log file ?

Likewise, what happens if a RESTART (e.g. as issued by logrotate when it runs into a POSTROTATE action) is issued while a commit is in progress ?